# Stack Overflow Error in java with small input set

Tags: java

I am trying to write quick sort in java. But getting a stack over flow error for very small set of inputs. In the createArray function I am taking input by the Scanner object.

Please somebody help me in this.

```
public class quickSort {

static int[] ar;
int number;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    CreatingArray ca = new CreatingArray();
    ar = ca.createArray();
    ca.printArray(ar);
    int len = ar.length;
    sort(0,(len-1));
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Array after QuickSort:");
    ca.printArray(ar);
}

public static void sort(int l,int h) {
    int i=l;
    int j=h;
    int temp =0;
    int pivot = ar[(l + (l+h)/2)];

    while(i <= j) {
        while(ar[i] < pivot) {
            i++;
        }
        while(ar[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
        }
        if (i<=j) {
            temp = ar[i];
            ar[i] = ar[j];
            ar[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }   
    }
    if(l<j){
        sort(l,j);
    }
    if(i<h) {
        sort(i,h);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int pivot = ar[(l + (l+h)/2)];
```

This line is wrong. It only gets the center point when `l == 0`. If, say, `l == 4 && h == 7` (e.g. the upper half of an 8-element array), you get `4 + (4+7)/2` which is `9` and thus outside the bounds. You really want `l + (h-l+1)/2`.

The first thing that can happen because of this is `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, but you never get that because you always recurse on the lower partition first and run into the second problem. Swap the two `if`s at the end of the function to see this in action.

The second thing that can happen is that, because `pivot` is not actually an element in the range `[i, j]`, the element search at the start of the loop can go crazy. In particular, `pivot` could be a very small value that is smaller than any in the range. The `i` search will terminate immediately (leaving `i == l` the way it started), while the `j` search will run way beyond `i`, which means the `if` won't be entered either, `i` still doesn't change, and the main loop terminates. Because `i` is unchanged, `i<h` is still true (assuming `l<h` was), and you enter the recursive call with exactly the same arguments you just had, which means the next call will do exactly the same thing as the current one, ending in infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I think your recursive calls don't end... debug your code with very small input - say 3 numbers... check when and how sort() is being called..